# Как правильно выбрать дату?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
#поиск даты и время в формате 4.14.2016_20.23

regex = re.compile(r'''
                (^[1-3])? #число
                ([0-9])
                (\.)
                (1)? #месяц
                (\d)
                (\.)
                (20) #год
                (\d)
                (\d)
                (_)
                ([0-2])#часы
                ([0-9])
                (\.)
                ([0-6])#минуты
                (\d)
                ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Регулярное выражение в принципе работает, за исключением того, что проходят строки вида '32.9.2017_00:01', '9.2.2016_29.25' и т.д.

Как исправить?

Comment: Вам столько круглых скобок принципиально, могу ицеликом написать, но столько скобок городить я рехнусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начало выражения такое сделайте:

```
^([1-2]\d|3[01]|\d)\.
```

надеюсь вам кол-во круглых скобок не принципиально, вообще не понятно зачем они вам в таком количестве. И даты возможно стоит проверять соответствующими функциями, ибо регулярки от 31 февраля никак не застрахованы

Comment: Не будет это выражение работать, например не пройдет  '4.9.2017_00:01'

Comment: @pynix почему не пройдет, еще как пройдет. заметьте я написал только _начало_ выражения, только для дня. Месяц вы сами можете закодировать по аналогии.

Comment: @pynix https://regex101.com/r/vK5aW1/1  отлично работает. вы внимательнее присмотритесь. числа 1n и 2n ИЛИ 3[01] ИЛИ \d - т.е. одна цифра. хотя эту одну цифру лучше сделать тогда [1-9], а то 0 день пройдет

Comment: Все, я понял. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте специализированный парсер

```
time.strptime("09.02.2016_20:00", "%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M")
```

Comment: Да я регулярные выражения по книжке учу, какие парсеры!)

Comment: Ну мы тут настоящие проблемы решаем. А то сами себе сложностей насоздавали - вот тогда сами и решайте %)

Comment: Ну если уже так серьезно подходить, как вы подходите, то ваш совет не подходит, ведь нужно _найти_ такую строку, а не _извлечь из строки данные_

Comment: Хм, это меняет задачу. В таком случае можно ограничиться базовым регеспом, после которого выполнять дополнительную проверку (потому что 29 февраля на високосный год очень сложно в регулярное выражение вложить)